# How far can I go with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms, client-side

I need to do as much as possible on the client side. In more details, I would like to use JavaScript to code an interface (which displays information to the user and which accepts and processes response from the user). I would like to use the web serve just to take a date file from there and then to send a modified data file back. In this respect I would like to know if the following is possible in JavaScript:

1. Can JavaScript read content of a external web page? In other words, on my local machine I run JavaScript which reads content of a given web page.
2. Can JavaScript process values filled in a HTML form? In other words, I use HTML and JavaScript to generate an HTML form. User is supposed to fill in the form and press a "Submit" button. Then data should be sent to the original HTML file (not to a web server). Then this data should be processed by JavaScript.
3. In the very end JavaScript will generate a local data-file and I want to send this file to a PHP web server. Can I do it with JavaScript?
4. Can I initiate an execution of a local program from JavaScript. To be more specific, the local program is written in Python.

I will appreciate any comments and answers.

Comment: “I need to do as much as possible on the client side” — Out of interest, why?

Comment: Paul, I would like to program a group game. And I want to have two versions of the game (from technical point of view). In the first case the game is based on a P2P approach (I use Python to establish connection between computers). In the second case I want to use a web server to play the game. And I do not want to do my job twice. So, I thought I can use JavaScript to program interaction interface. And than I can apply this interface for both P2P and web-server approaches (the only difference is how the data was obtained, but the available data is displayed by the same code).

Comment: Point 4: Configure the machine to register a protocol like "myap://" or save a file and associate the extension with a program. Any of them require to configure machine before running the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It could technically, but can't in reality due to the [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This applies to both reading and writing external content. The best you can do is load an iframe with a different domain's page in it - but you can't access it programmatically. You can work around this in IE, see Andy E's answer.
2. Yes for the first part, mmmm not really for the second part - you can submit a form to a HTML page and read GET arguments using Javascript, but it's *very* limited (recommended maximum size of data around 1024 bytes). You should probably have all the intelligence on one page.
3. You can generate a file locally for the user to download using [**Downloadify**](http://www.downloadify.info/). Generating a *file* and uploading it to a server won't be possible without user interaction. Generating data and sending it to a server as POST data should be possible, though.
4. This is very, very difficult. Due to security restrictions, in most browsers, it's mostly not possible without installing an extension or similar. Your best bet might be Internet Explorer's proprietary scripting languages (WScript, VBScript) in conjuction with the "security zones" model but I doubt whether the execution of local files is possible even there nowadays.

Comment: 1. But I do not want to execute something on another site. I just want to have an access to the content of a publicly available web page. I just read (not execute).
2. What exactly are limitations about the reading GET arguments? As far as I can get the values of the variable, I am happy.

Comment: 1. Yes, still not possible. The usual way of doing this is using a Proxy server-side script that runs on the same domain as the requested page, and fetches the content, but even that won't work if your page is located on the user's PC. You can use a proxy if this page we are talking about is on a web server. 2. Size limitations - it is safe to transport a maximum of approx. 1024 bytes that way.

Comment: Good answer, Pekka :-) With regards to 1, 3 and 4, I think IE is the only real option here.

Comment: @Andy E cheers :) I didn't know IE can do as much as you outline in your answer, good job!

Comment: @Pekka: I mostly deal in Windows Desktop Gadgets, built on the IE engine.  It's pretty much my job to find ways of doing things that aren't natively available ;-)

Comment: The *same origin policy* can be overridden by using JSONP (JSON with padding). So have a look at that, as well, if the json format fits your requirements for the external file

Answer (score 2):

Using Internet Explorer with a local file, you can do some of what you're trying to do:

1. It's true that pages are limited by the same origin policy (see Pekka's link).  But this can be worked around in IE using the [WinHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(VS.85).aspx) COM interface.
2. As Pekka mentioned, the best you can manage is GET requests (using `window.location.search`).  POST request variables are completely unobtainable.
3. You can use the COM interface for [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh(VS.85).aspx) to read & write local text files.
4. You can use the [WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(VS.85).aspx) interface's `Exec` method to execute a local program.

So just about everything you asked is attainable, if you're willing to use Internet Explorer.  The COM interfaces will require explicit permission to run (a la the yellow alert bar that appears).  You could also look at creating a [Windows Desktop Gadget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834142.aspx) (Vista or Win 7) or a [HTML Application (HTA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx) to achieve your goal.

Failing all that, turn your computer into a real server using [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and write your pages in PHP.

Comment: However, you can do far, far more with Firefox using XUL, Prism, Weave and many other tools. Firefox is built to do such things and they'll work on any platform.

Comment: @Rob: quote `XUL, Prism, and many other tools`.  Everything in my answer is possible just from having Windows installed.  Not in the slightest bit complicated.  We're not talking about doing `far, far more`, we're talking about doing what the OP specified in his question and, in reality, you can do just about anything with JavaScript and COM in IE, as I'm sure you can with Fx, XUL, etc.  You're very welcome to provide your own answer suggesting those tools :-)

Answer (score 2):

see i got what you want to do
best things is do following

1. choose a javascript library (eg:jquery,dojo,yui etc), i use jquery.this will decrease some of your load
2. inspite of saving forms data in in a local file, store them in local variables process them and send them to server (for further processing like adding/updating database etc) using XMLHttp request, and when webservice returns data process that data and update dom.

## i am showing you a sample

--this is dom

```
Name:<input type='text' id='name' />

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='submit()'>Submit Form</a>
<br>
<div id='target'></div>

--this is js
function submit()
{
var _name=$('#name').val();// collect text box's data
//now validate it or do any thing you want

callWebservice(_name,_suc,_err);
//above call service fn has to be created by you where you send this data
//this function automatically do xmlHttprequest etc for you
//you have to create it ur self 
}

//call this fn when data is sucessfully returned from server
function _suc(data)
{
//webservice has returned data sucessefully 
//data= data from server, may be in this case= "Hello user Name"; (name = filled in input box);
//update this data in target div(manipulate dom with new data);
$('#target').html(data);
}
function _err()
{
//call this fn when error occurs on server
}
```

// in reality most of the work is done using json. i have shown u the basic idea of how to use js to manipulate dom and call servcies and do rest things. this way we avoid page-reloads and new data is visible to viewer

Comment: But how web server can return data? I just was told to that JavaScript cannot read anything from the web server.

Comment: to get data from server u have to make XMLHttp request. this XMLHttp object has got many properties one of which is url where u specify which url will process this data.read some online artices on ajax, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer saying there's a lot you can do, but then in the comment to the OP, you say

> "I would like to program a group game."

And so, my answer becomes only do on the client side what you are able and willing to double check on the server side. [Never Trust the Client](http://www.raphkoster.com/gaming/laws.shtml)!

> And I do not want to do my job twice.

If you are going to do things on the client side, you will have to do it twice, or else be subject to rampant cheating.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same question when we started our project.
In the end we moved everything we could on the JS side. Here's our stack:

**The backend** receives and send JSON data exclusively.
We use Erlang, but Python would be the same. It handles the authentication/security and the storage.

**The frontend**, is in HTML+CSS for visual elements and JS for the logic.
A JS template engine converts the JSON into HTML. We've built [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure), but there are plenty of others available. MVC can be an overkill on the browser side, but IMO using a template engine is the least separation you can do.

The response time is amazing. Once the page and the JS/CSS are loaded(fresh or from the cache), only the data cross the network for each request.